# Find Difference among two Different Columns in two Different Sub SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the difference between the TotalPendency  column and TotalDisposal column.

The query is below:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
         NextDate, 
         COUNT(CaseNo) AS TotalPendency, 
         'Pending' AS DisposalState  
     FROM 
         dbo.Main_Cause_List 
     WHERE 
         NextDate = '2021-06-05' 
         AND DisposalState = 'Pending'   
     GROUP BY
         NextDate)
     MINUS
     (SELECT NextDate, COUNT(CaseNo) AS TotalDisposal, 'Disposed-off' AS DisposalState  
      FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List 
      WHERE NextDate = '2021-06-05' 
        AND DisposalState = 'Disposed-off'   
      GROUP BY NextDate) AS TotalPend;
```

and I get these errors:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT 
    NextDate, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) AS TotalPendency,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Disposed-of' THEN 1 END) AS TotalDisposal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) -
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Disposed-of' THEN 1 END) AS Diff
FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List
WHERE NextDate = '2021-06-05'
GROUP BY NextDate;
```

The `MINUS` operator is for taking differences between two sets of records, not between the various counts in your query (the latter which you seem to really want here).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest conditional aggregation, but phrase it as:

```
SELECT NextDate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Pending' THEN 1 
                WHEN DisposalState = 'Disposed-of' THEN -1
           END) AS Diff
FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List
WHERE NextDate = '2021-06-05'
GROUP BY NextDate;
```

Comment: SELECT NextDate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Pending' THEN 1 
                WHEN DisposalState = 'Disposed-of' THEN -1
           END) AS Diff
FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List
WHERE NextDate = '2021-06-05'
GROUP BY NextDate;

Answer (score 0):

I think using join can solve this problem.this shall run in MySQL.maybe MS-SQL has some difference.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
         NextDate, 
         COUNT(CaseNo) AS TotalPendency, 
         'Pending' AS DisposalState  
     FROM 
         dbo.Main_Cause_List 
     WHERE 
         NextDate = '2021-06-05' 
         AND DisposalState = 'Pending'   
     GROUP BY
         NextDate) as TotalPend

    left join 

    (
        SELECT NextDate, COUNT(CaseNo) AS TotalDisposal, 'Disposed-off' AS DisposalState  
        FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List 
        WHERE NextDate = '2021-06-05' 
        AND DisposalState = 'Disposed-off'   
      GROUP BY NextDate) AS TotalDisposed

    on (TotalDisposed.NextDate=TotalPend.NextDate)
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    NextDate, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) AS TotalPendency,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Disposed-off' THEN 1 END) AS TotalDisposal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) -
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Disposed-off' THEN 1 END) AS DateWiseTotalPendency
FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List
WHERE NextDate = '2021-06-14'
GROUP BY NextDate;
```